# str_replace on string only if it INCLUDES a whitespace

Tags: php

I have a substitution code that replaces all instances of XD with an XD smiley face... thing is, should a link include the string 'XD', it then breaks the link.

I want it to only replace the XD, if it is followed by a whitespace, as in 'XD ', except I can't seem to get it to work (tried &nbsp, /\s/ and `&#32;` as in 'XD&nbsp')

Chances are I'm getting something really obvious wrong, but I can't find any help (all of it seems to be about removing whitespace, not requiring it), so I'm hoping someone can help me.

Here's the code for reference:

```
 function BB_CODE($content) {
   $content = str_replace("XD", "<img src=\"images/smilies/icon_xd.gif\" alt=\"XD\">", $content);
}
```

The content is user input. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You should surround "XD" with %

```
$content= str_replace("%XD%", "<img src=\"images/smilies/icon_xd.gif\" alt=\"XD\">", $content);
```

EDIT : 
Or using preg_replace

```
preg_replace("/XD/", "<img src=\"images/smilies/icon_xd.gif\" alt=\"XD\">", $content);
```

Comment: Hm, it still just seems to nullify the code... link vanishes and the text stays at 'XD'

Comment: Try this one using preg_replace 
`preg_replace("/XD/", "<img src=\"images/smilies/icon_xd.gif\" alt=\"XD\">", $input_lines);`

Answer (score 0):

So you want to replace XD only if it's alone?

```
preg_replace('/\bXD\b/', '(ಠ‿ಠ)', "Then I was like XD")
```

Use `\b` to watch for word boundaries instead of `\s`. This means it works at the beginning and the end of string too, like in my example.

With `preg_replace()` there are two common gotchas:

- **The separator char**, I used `/` here by convention but in my own code I prefer `%`. You could write the regex as `'%\bXD\b%'` with the same meaning.
- **Escaping the backslashes**, I used a single quoted string so I don't have to escape the backslash in `\b`. If you use double qoutes, you have to escape it, like so: `"/\\bXD\\b/"`

Comment: Hm, the link is still vanishing... I'm testing it using a link, then the smiley, the smiley shows up in this instance, but the link is just replaced by an empty space

Comment: This code will not replace links. This is happening somewhere else. Check the sanitization functions of your forum.

Comment: I'm not trying to replace links, thing is if I have a link 'www.XDlalala.com', the link breaks up because of the XD replacement code interfering

Comment: This doesn't happen with the regex I provided. What could happen is if somebody wrote `http://XD.com` then XD is considered as a spearate word. Use `'/(^|\s)XD($|\s)/'` if you want to be more restrictive. But then "XD." (notice the period) would not be replaced.